# Prove that if $(X_n,T_n)$ has weight $\le$ to $m$ that's an infinite cardinal number, its product space has weight $\le m$ .

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if each space $(X_n,T_n), \forall n \in \Bbb N,$ has weight not greater than $m$ for some infinite cardinal number, prove that the weight of the product space is not greater than $m$.

So since it's not greater than $m$, it's less than or equal to $m$.  Then if $w(X_n,T_n) = m, \forall n \in \Bbb N$, then the weight of the product space is $\le m.$

As an example:

So if each $w(X_n,T_n) = \Bbb N$, then the product space should be $\le \Bbb N$.  But isn't the cardinality of a countably infinite product of countable spaces uncountable?

Comment: You refer to "each space $(X_n, T_n)$ but give no hint at the cardinality of the index space.  Is the collection of $n$s finite, countable, uncountable, unconstrained?  In your second paragraph, the collection of $n$ seems to be $\Bbb{N}$.  Is that the intended collection or merely an example?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: No, the product will be uncountable — at least the cardinality of $\Bbb R$, in fact — unless all but finitely many of the spaces are one-point spaces. The first paragraph of the accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main result is basic [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication).  Each space has a basis consisting of no more than $m$ elements.  The basis of the product is the collection of products of finitely many basis elements (no more than one from any one $X_n$) and infinitely many $X_n$.  There is $1$ product basis element with all members of the product being the whole space.  There are at most $m + m + m + \cdots \leq \aleph_0 \cdot m = m$ product basis elements with only one member not a whole space.  (For the last inequality:  Since $m$ is an infinite cardinal and $\aleph_0$ is the least infinite cardinal, $\aleph_0 \cdot m \leq m \cdot m \leq m$.  There are other reduction paths as well.)  Summing over $k$, the number of elements of the product basis element that are not the whole space, yields an upper bound of $\sum_{k \in \Bbb{N}} \aleph_0^k m^k$, where the first factor estimates the cardinality of choices of from which spaces we do not take the whole space and the second factor estimates the cardinality of choices of basis elements from each of those spaces.  But this is the sum of $\aleph_0$ copies of $m$, so is $m$.

Comment: Just to clarify, the second paragraph is what helped me understand the problem.

$w(X_i,T_i) \le m \Rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} w(X_i,T_i) \le \ card(\Bbb N) \times m = m.$

Comment: @Oliver: And the second paragraph is fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I have no idea how I crosswired "union" and "product" in one paragraph and not the other.  (As in, "countable union of countable sets ...")  Meh.  I don't think there's anything worth saving from the first paragraph, so it is excised.

Comment: @Eric: I figured that that was probably what had happened.